# Is there any way to quantify edge information contained in an image

Tags: image, image-processing

I have two versions of a same image one is original image and one is smoothed version of it. I want to know how much edge information is contained in both images as numerical value not as an image like Perceptual quality metric etc. Is there any method to calculate edge information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily from the commandline with Imagemagick which is installed on most Linux distros and available for OSX and Windows.

First convert to grayscsle then do a Canny Edge detection then count the white pixels.

I'm not at a proper computer, just an iPhone, so I can't check but it will look like this:

```
convert image.jpg -colorspace gray   \
    -canny 0x1+5%+10%                \                    \
    \( +clone -evaluate set 0 \) \
    -metric AE -compare          \
    -format "%[distortion]" info:
287
```

Remove the last 3 lines and replace with a simple image filename to see the resulting edge detected image rather than count the white pixels.

Divide the number of white pixels by the product of the image height and width to normalize results for differently sized images.

Comment: But it will only tell the ratio of how many white pixels (means detected edges) are in the input image. Is there not any other method which is more sound than this procedure. By the way thanks for your answer. i have tried this solution and smoothed image has less number of white pixels in detected edge image by canny edge detection method.

Comment: Mmmm... not sure what you want. Your question asks how to quantify edge pixels, which implies counting them, and you say my answer only tells you how many there are - which, to my mind, is the same thing. Maybe you need to better explain what you mean/want...

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolute measure for edge information, since what constitutes an edge depends on the thresholds you apply on the luminance-gradients. What I would do is to consider the distribution of gradients (take e.g. Sobel Operator in x- and y-direction so that the magnitude in each point is then sqrt(Gradient_x^2 + Gradient_y^2). From the distibution of Gradients, you can then use a quantile (e.g. 70% which is a typical value in the Canny case), which is fore sure lower for a smoothed Picture than for an unsmoothed.